# How to implement a custom field available for Views?

Tags: views

I'm making my first steps authoring simple modules. I would like to make my life easier by implementing a custom field for taxonomy views, a field named: "Taxonomy term: Arbitrary ascendant" so that it gets a term's ascendant at the given hierarchy level, as returned by `taxonomy_get_parents_all`.

Similarly, for content Views, I would like to provide a field configuration that would allow for ascendant tests for any term on an entity.

Could anyone point me to the Views API functions that must be taken into account to make this module properly authored?

Answer (score 1):

Try [views.api.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/7)

> Describe hooks provided by the Views module.

& [Views hooks](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/group/views_hooks/7)

> Hooks that can be implemented by other modules in order to implement
>   the Views API.

Comment: +1. But please consider adding some actual text, may be a teaser from the above docs file so your answer is "compact"

Answer (score 0):

A way I have gone about this recently is to add a place holder field to a content type. I then create a module that provides a tpl.php for this field and use a preprocess function to actually calculate it.

Comment: Yes, that's one way, I am also able to do another - with a custom formatter, which I already got working. My goal however is to start doing more "native" things... Thanks though.

Comment: I agree. While I like having what I've done in a module so it is at least theme independent, I'm still trying to work out a way to have that available outside of views and to be more tightly integrated into the field.